# KafkaConsumer prevents other asyncio.Task from running properly

Tags: python, apache-kafka, discord.py, python-asyncio, kafka-python

I am trying to create an async Python app that subscribes to a Kafka topic and `print`s out the received messages via the `asyncio.Task` named `echo_kafka_msgs_task`.

At the same time, there is a second `asyncio.Task` named `ping_task` that prints out an incrementing integer every second.

However, the integer is only printed out once, and no longer prints out when `echo_kafka_msgs_task` has started.

Why is this happening, and how can we fix this?

```
import asyncio
import json
import discord
from kafka import KafkaConsumer


class DiscordBot(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.consumer = KafkaConsumer(
            "my_topic",
            value_deserializer=lambda m: json.loads(m.decode('utf-8'))
        )
        
    async def on_ready(self):
        ping_task = asyncio.create_task(self.ping())
        echo_kafka_msgs_task = asyncio.create_task(self.echo_kafka_msgs())
        
    async def echo_kafka_msgs(self):
        while True:
            self._logger.info("Waiting for new messages...")
            for msg in self.consumer:
                print(msg.value)
            
    async def ping(self):
        i = 0
        while True:
            print("i=", i)
            i += 1
            await asyncio.sleep(1)    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = DiscordBot()
    client.run("my_token")
```

Comment: It seems that `kafka`  is a blocking (synchronous) library not suited for asynchronous projects, you could use something like [`aiokafka`](https://pypi.org/project/aiokafka/) instead, which supports async programming.

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński Tried `aiokafka` and now its working as expected! Thanks!

Comment: I'm also interested to learn about how an `asyncio` event loop can get blocked by something synchronous.

Comment: You just did learn that :-).  Only code containing an "await" expression will co-operate with other tasks.  Only await expressions yield control back to the event loop, which is the trigger that allows other tasks to run.

Comment: @AthenaWisdom, hello! Did you solve the problem? I got stuck with the same problem, where `kafka-python`'s producer does not work in `multiprocessing.Process`